# Can't display response returned from Spring MVC controller using JSON and JQuery

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a simple `JQuery` function which calls my `Spring MVC` controller:

```
function createDatabaseRecord() {
    if (isFormValid()) {
        $.getJSON(
                "${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}${databaseConfigUrl}",
                {name:$('#idName').val(),
                    databaseName:$('#idDatabaseName').val(),
                    hostName:$('#idHostName').val(),
                    username:$('#idUsername').val(),
                    password:$('#idPassword').val()},
                function (data) {
                    var html = '<span>' + data + '</span>';
                    $('#idMessage').html(html);
                }
        );
    }
}
```

The function is invoked when I click the button, everything is fine. The problem is that this line: `$('#idMessage').html(html);` does not work as expected. I have a `<div>` element inside the same `JSP` page.

```
<div id="idMessage">
</div>
```

My Spring controller method which is invoked by that function:

```
@RequestMapping(value = DATABASE_CONFIG_RECORD_MAPPING, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
String createDatabaseConfiguration(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "databaseName", required = true) String databaseName,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "hostName", required = true) String hostName,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "username", required = true) String username,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "password", required = true) String password) {
    try {
        DatabaseConfig config = new DatabaseConfig();
        config.setName(name);
        config.setDatabaseName(databaseName);
        config.setHostName(hostName);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        configService.save(config);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception while create database configuration record.", ex);
        return "Error occurred while creating database configuration record: " + ex.getMessage();
    }
    return "Database configuration record successfully created.";
}
```

I can see in the FireBug that response came to me:

[image]. This is the message: **Database configuration record successfully created.** I expect to be show in that `<div>` element, but it is not displayed. Does someone know where might be the problem? If you need some more code, please ask.

Comment: If you console.log(data); before setting the the html, what does it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is not in JSON format.

Try this snippet in your controller:

```
return Collections.singletonMap("result", "Database configuration record successfully created");
```

And use it in javascript like this:

```
var html = '<span>' + data.result + '</span>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm definitely not an expert in Java (though it looks ok) but think your problem comes from the fact that you're using jQuery's `getJSON` method but your view is just returning plain text.

You'll need to either convert your response to JSON or switch to a more manual AJAX request using `$.get` or `$.ajax` instead.

Comment: If I change `getJSON` to `ajax`, I am getting: `NetworkError: 400 Bad Request`. This is not working.

Comment: My apologies. I originally had just `$.ajax` but that requires more options to control it. I added in using just `$.get` as an alternative. The [jQuery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax) has all the information you'll need to choose which method you should call.